# Is it possible to check a user name in a mysqli table before allowing a code to run?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a basic log in page. The page will be used to log the username and unix time of failed log ins.

Is it possible to look at the username before allowing the user to enter a password and if the attempts is 5 or over to disable them for 30 minutes.

I have searched the web but can't find anything, the other solution was to look at the table before allowing the code to proceed, but again have a bit of a brain freeze, am sure it easy enough but would prefer to stop the user earlier?

I have attached the check page just so you can see what I am attempting.

```
Include("include/conn.php");
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysqli_select_db('DATABASE');
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
// encrypt password
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);
//see if account is locked
//STUCK HERE if looking at amount of attements before allowing code to run. 
//look up username and pasword match
$sqli="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Username='$myusername' and     Password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sqli);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $Unique_Id and redirect to file "home.php"
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("Unique_Id");
    header("location:home.php");
}
//if log in if not sucsesfull
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    //update attempt log with attempt +1 and unix time
    $sql_query_update = "UPDATE TABLE SET
        Attempts = Attempts+1,time =  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())
        WHERE TABLE.Username ='$myusername'";
    mysql_query( $sql_query_update );
    //close mysql
    mysql_Close();
}
?>
```

I am aware of the outdated code but this is for testing only as I am struggling configuring `mysqli` on my virtual server.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: (md5 is not safe and you don't need to have stripslashes)

Comment: Nickolas, i have a text and password input box (HTML) which $POST to the above page, is there a way to check the username for failed attempts before allowing the password to be entered? MD 5 any suggestions to a alternative some people say its ok and some say its not ( like yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. This will not work as they are different API's.
2. I would recommend using a key and salt to encrypt your password (using sha256+) as `md5` is very weak. The key would be stored in your database, and the salt on the server.

   `hash('sha256', $keyFromDb . $saltFromServer . $userPassword);`
3. Use prepared statements and binded parameters to prevent against any level of SQL injection.

To answer your question; yes it's possible to check the user attempts for the username. You are on the right path.

Comment: @NicholasPickering Whoops, meant a key.

Comment: You've still got some cleaning up to do: statement 2 still says "hash", and your variable names are backwards from what you said.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by simply inserting the bad attempts into a table with the timestamp. Then checking to see if this is above three: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM error_table WHERE error_time < 1800 AND user_id = $user_id`. (Or username, or whatever). This way you don't have to keep track of the number of failed attempts, they're readily available from the `COUNT` statement. If you want a bit more of a verbose method, then have a disabled timestamp which triggers once the count >= 3.

As some notes:

1. You don't need stripslashes
2. If you care about your user's passwords at all, use something more complicated than MD5, and ideally you should have a salt string of some form.
3. You are selecting your database with `mysqli` and you are running your selects and updates with `mysql`. You don't mean to do that, and even if it is working (if you, say, have selected the database in conn.php) this code is an invite for a bug.
4. `include` is lower-case. It does not matter strictly, but it is faux pas to capitalize a function which is supposed to be lower-cased.

Comment: Thanks, re the stripslahes i was not too concerned as this will only be available for computers based in a few locations not from outside , however looking into the future it may be so i will research.  the mysqli and mysql was purely due to a configuration issue which i will resolve later. and i have corrected the include. thanks for the answer i am still investigating looking at the username before showing the password box, and hash/salt protection. A bit indepth for a newbie but i like learning. Thanks

Comment: Storing these kinds of errors is NOT the best way. It's much better to store them in a temporary location like a session or a cookie... Databases are for data that plans to get used on a long term basis. You're padding your database with useless information.

Comment: The problem with storing them in a session or a cookie is that the user can simply delete his cookie data and get around it. An access restriction table is a far better option.

Comment: thanks for all the replies re the security issue, found a great example and have a more secure log in.

Comment: // generate 64 char long random string "salt", a string to "encrypt" the password hash
// this is a basic salt, you might replace this with a more advanced function
//@see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)
$this->user_salt =substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'), 0, 64);
// double md5 hash the plain password + salt
//$user_password_hashed = md5(md5($_POST['user_password'].$user_salt));
// hash the combined string of password+salt via the sha256 algorithm, result is a 64 char string